# Shimano Ultegra CS-6800 11/32 replacement?

Tags: road-bike, shimano, cassette, shimano-di2

I currently have Ultegra CS-6800, 11/32 w/Di2 on my bike.  I've been wanting to get a second set of wheels and see that CS-6800 series is now replaced with the CS-R8000 series.  If I move to the R8000 platform using the same 11/32 gearing, am I going to have issue with detuning of the shifting system or should it be a 1 to 1 swap?
Thanks
Greg

Answer (score 2):

I think you must be referring to the new cassette on the second set if wheels.

Sprocket spacing remains the same on Shimano 11 speed across generations. The new Ultegra R8000 cassette will work perfectly well with the 6800 derailleur, maybe even a bit better.

The only trouble you may have is that the cassette may be in a slightly different position on the second set of wheels.

Comment: All 11-speed Shimano cassettes from 105 to Dura-Ace will fit the 6800 RD with the caveat that the maximum number of teeth is 32. The only difference is the material of the cogs which influences the weight and of course the price.

Comment: To clarify - yes - the R8000 would be going on the new second set of wheels.  So I would be rotating a set with CS-6800 with a set of R8000 (both 11/32) with the hopes of not having to tweak my Di2 setup.